# Bootstrap 4 Input file no se ve en el label el nombre del fichero subido

Tags: html, archivo, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tags-input

Este fragmento de código sube el fichero:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Imagen</span>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="imagen"  name="imagen"   capture="camera" accept="image/*">
        <label id="casillaFileName" class="custom-file-label" >Examinar...</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero cuando selecciono el fichero sigue poniendo `Examinar...` en vez del nombre del fichero que he **seleccionado**.

Para ello dice la **documentación** que debo hacer mediante **jQuery** de la siguiente forma:

```
$('.custom-file-input').on('change', function(event) {
    var inputFile = event.currentTarget;
    $(inputFile).parent()
        .find('.custom-file-label')
        .html(inputFile.files[0].name);
});
```

Comment: Lo he probado y el código funciona ¿Cómo tienes organizado el documento? A lo mejor estás poniendo la función antes de que el HTML y no hay ningún elemento que corresponda a las etiquetas

Comment: eso era , tenia la funcion antes de llamar a jquery

Comment: si utlizas jquery no es necesario hacer referencia al elemento a quien se le asigna el listener basta con un `$(this).parent()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos acabo de probar tu codigo Jquery y con Bootstrap 4 y funciona a la perfección, deberias revisar si estas colocando bien las librerias(jquery) o si aparece algun error por consola:

```js
$('.custom-file-input').on('change', function(event) {
    var inputFile = event.currentTarget;
    $(inputFile).parent()
        .find('.custom-file-label')
        .html(inputFile.files[0].name);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  
  
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Imagen</span>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-file">
            <label id="casillaFileName" class="custom-file-label" >Examinar...</label>
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="imagen"  name="imagen"   capture="camera" accept="image/*">

    </div>
</div>




    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```